# Blazor's ::deep CSS feature for child component when it is inside container component

Tags: css, blazor

I have 3 components: `DTMyComponent`, `DTContainer` and `DTChild`.

Here's the setup of components:

---

`DTMyComponent.razor`

```
<DTContainer>
    <h1>Parent content</h1>
    <DTChild />
</DTContainer>
```

---

`DTMyComponent.razor.css`

```
::deep h1{
    color: blue;
}
```

---

`DTContainer.razor`

```
<div>
    <h1>Container content</h1>
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

---

`DTChild`

```
<h1>Child content</h1>
```

---

Result is that `<h1>Child content</h1>` is not blue, as I would expect it would be.

I expected that it would be because it was blue when:

`DTMyComponent.razor`

```
<div>
    <h1>Parent content</h1>
    <DTChild />
</div>
```

---

Also, it wasn't blue when

`DTMyComponent.razor`

```
<h1>Parent content</h1>
<DTChild />
```

But that's fine, I've read the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and it does explain that `::deep` doesn't work without the container element.

---

Though, I do have a container **component** (`DTContainer`) that I want my `DTChild` to be inside of.

The question is, what CSS should I put in my `DTMyComponent.razor.css` to target the `h1` element of `DTChild` when I setup everything like I explained at the top?

Answer (score 1):

I'm rubber ducking here...

I just wrapped everything in my `DTMyComponent` in `<div>` element like this:

```
<div>
    <DTContainer>
        <h1>Parent content</h1>
        <DTChild />
    </DTContainer>
</div>
```

And now `<h1>` is blue, though every `<h1>` is blue, but it's fine because I just set a custom class for `DTChild` and then it called `::deep` on that CSS class.

Feel free to change the title of this question. I don't know how to explain this situation better in a few words.

Comment: I still think we should be able to do what you asked for in the question.  I can't think of a way.